# Rolling Mean with Time Offset Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average, rolling-average

I have a data set of timestamps & values in pandas. The interval between timestamps is ~12 seconds over a total timespan of roughly one year but sometimes there are missing points (i.e., the time series is irregular so I can't use fixed window sizes).

I want to compute the rolling averages of the values over 1 minute intervals but I'm not getting the behavior that I expected. I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062652/pandas-rolling-sum-of-last-five-minutes) but that was using the sum and also pre-pandas 0.19.0. I am using Pandas 0.23.4.

**Sample Data**

```
Time, X
2018-02-02 21:27:00,    75.4356
2018-02-02 21:27:12,    78.29821
2018-02-02 21:27:24,    73.098345
2018-02-02 21:27:36,    78.3331
2018-02-02 21:28:00,    79.111
```

Note that `2018-02-02 21:27:48` is missing.

For a rolling sum, I could just fill the missing values with 0s but for the mean, I don't want the missing points being counted as real data points (for example, I want the window to be sum(data points over given interval) / number of data points in interval).

I'd like to do it for varying segments of time (i.e., 1min, 5min, 15min, 1hr, etc).

The closest I got to getting actual values was to do:

**Code**

```
df['rolling_avg']=df.rolling('1T',on='Time').X.mean()
```

My understanding is that would be the 1 minute rolling averages.

But then, I'm not sure how to interpret the output. I would have expected NaNs for the first 1+1 minute since there is nothing to base the rolled average on but instead I have values.

**Output**

```
    Time                X         rolling_avg
0   2018-02-02 21:27:00 75.4356   75.435600
1   2018-02-02 21:27:12 78.29821  76.866905
2   2018-02-02 21:27:24 73.098345 75.610718
3   2018-02-02 21:27:36 78.3331   76.291314
4   2018-02-02 21:28:00 79.111    77.210164
```

Basically, in this output, `df[1].rolling_avg` is `(Value[0]+Value[1])/2`, though the interval was 12 seconds, not 1 minute.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do or do I need to write a for-loop to do this manually?

Comment: Give this a try... df['rolling_avg']=df.rolling('60s').X.mean()

Comment: @run-out That gives `ValueError: window must be an integer`

Comment: Further to my answer below, I wonder if your datetime is properly formatted. It won't work if it's a string.

Comment: Doesn't the output look consistent? You're looking for averages of 1-minute intervals..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in your data. And then maybe I'm not solving the problem. I got the same error using your data, but it worked when I tried this.

```
import  pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

time = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/02/2018', freq='12s')
time

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:12',
               '2018-01-01 00:00:24', '2018-01-01 00:00:36',
               '2018-01-01 00:00:48', '2018-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2018-01-01 00:01:12', '2018-01-01 00:01:24',
               '2018-01-01 00:01:36', '2018-01-01 00:01:48',
               ...
               '2018-01-01 23:58:12', '2018-01-01 23:58:24',
               '2018-01-01 23:58:36', '2018-01-01 23:58:48',
               '2018-01-01 23:59:00', '2018-01-01 23:59:12',
               '2018-01-01 23:59:24', '2018-01-01 23:59:36',
               '2018-01-01 23:59:48', '2018-01-02 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=7201, freq='12S')

B = np.random.randint(0, 9, 7201)

df = pd.DataFrame(B, time)
df['rolling_avg']=df.rolling('60s', min_periods=3).mean()
df.head(20)

    0                rolling_avg
2018-01-01 00:00:00 5   NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:12 0   NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:24 1   2.0
2018-01-01 00:00:36 0   1.5
2018-01-01 00:00:48 6   2.4
2018-01-01 00:01:00 7   2.8
2018-01-01 00:01:12 6   4.0
2018-01-01 00:01:24 3   4.4
2018-01-01 00:01:36 7   5.8
2018-01-01 00:01:48 6   5.8
2018-01-01 00:02:00 2   4.8
2018-01-01 00:02:12 6   4.8
2018-01-01 00:02:24 1   4.4
2018-01-01 00:02:36 0   3.0
2018-01-01 00:02:48 8   3.4
2018-01-01 00:03:00 2   3.4
2018-01-01 00:03:12 5   3.2
2018-01-01 00:03:24 8   4.6
2018-01-01 00:03:36 4   5.4
2018-01-01 00:03:48 1   4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You say: *But then, I'm not sure how to interpret the output. I would have expected NaNs for the first 1+1 minute since there is nothing to base the rolled average on but instead I have values.*

The method `.rolling()` takes all values into account where the index is in a 1-minute interval. The interval is open to the left and closed to the right ([by default, but you can change this; use the optional parameter `closed`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)). Its right end is the current index ([you can change this,too; use the optional parameter `center`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)).
In your case, the first such interval is ]`2018-02-02 21:26:00`, `2018-02-02 21:27:00`], which contains only the index `2018-02-02 21:27:00`. Therefore the mean is computed over only one value.

Hence I actually think that this is the exact behaviour you want.