# pandas dataframe - rolling windows based on column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I've dataframe like that:

| price | period |
| --- | --- |
| 124.22 | 5 |
| 126.51 | 6 |
| 121.3 | 6 |
| 125.25 | 4 |

`df['lowest'] = df['price'].rolling(window=30).min().shift(1)`

Now the rolling is applied base on 30 window. I need to apply for each row the corresponding  period. Es:
For first line price = 124.22 , window = 5

Something like that (this code not working...):

`df['lowest'] = df['price'].rolling(window=df['period']).min().shift(1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas rolling computation with window based on values instead of counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300768/pandas-rolling-computation-with-window-based-on-values-instead-of-counts)